# Mensagem Value error

Tags: python

Boa tarde, surgiu-me uma mensagem de erro de operands coul not be broadcast together with shapes (256,) (268,) 
a imagem mostra o erro[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o código é o seguinte:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from lib_nrf24 import NRF24
import time
import spidev
import math
import string
import numpy as np

def dec_to_bin(ascii):
     binary=format(''.join('{:04b}'.format(x) for x in ascii))
     bits=np.transpose( list(map(int, np.transpose( list(binary)))))
     return bits

def convert_to_ascii(text):
    aux=format(''.join(str(ord(char)) for char in text))
    ascii= list(map(int,list(aux)))
    return ascii

#===============InicializaÃ§Ã£o Radio do NRF24L01=======================
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

pipes = [[0xE8, 0xE8, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xE1], [0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xE1]]

radio = NRF24(GPIO, spidev.SpiDev())
radio.begin(0, 17)
radio.setCRCLength(NRF24.CRC_DISABLED)
radio.setPayloadSize(32)
radio.setChannel(0x76)
radio.setDataRate(NRF24.BR_1MBPS)
radio.setPALevel(NRF24.PA_MIN)
radio.setAutoAck(False)
radio.enableDynamicPayloads()
radio.enableAckPayload()
radio.openReadingPipe(1, pipes[1])
radio.disableCRC()
#radio.printDetails()

radio.startListening()

#========palavra a receber===================
palavra="01234567890123456789012345678910"

#==============Texto inicio programa===================
print("\n")
print("====Inicio Envio Dados Sensor2======")
time.sleep(.1)
print("\n")
#=======Conversao (palavra)==================================================
ascii=convert_to_ascii(palavra)
ascii_aux=np.array(ascii)
erros=np.sum(np.array((np.array(ascii)-np.array(ascii_aux))!=0, dtype=int))
bits=dec_to_bin(ascii)
#print("Bits(palavra)=",' '.join('{:04b}'.format(x) for x in ascii))
##print('Bits(array)= ',format(','.join('{}'.format(x) for x in bits)))
#=======================Mensagem Recebida====================================
while(1):

    while not radio.available(0):
        time.sleep(1 /100)

    receivedMessage= []
    radio.read(receivedMessage, radio.getDynamicPayloadSize())


    string = ""

    for n in receivedMessage:
        string += chr(n)
        ascii=convert_to_ascii(string)
        ascii_aux2=np.array(ascii)
        bits_rx=dec_to_bin(ascii)

##    print("recebido", ascii_aux2)
##    print("palavra_", ascii_aux)
    print("Bits(recebidos)=",' '.join('{:04b}'.format(n) for n in ascii))
    erros=np.sum(np.array((bits-bits_rx)!=0, dtype=int))
    print("Erros= ", erros)
```

Comment: O que é `bits` e `bits_rx`? E qual o resultado esperado da subtração dos dois?

Comment: Bits é a variável palavra escrita em binário, bits_rx é a palavra recebida do arduino para o raspberry pi convertida em binario , depois é feita a operação sutração para saber o numero de bits errados no total de cada trasmissão a cada 5 segundos